# Select dropdown from date range

Tags: php

Is there a simple if statement to default select the correct date from the dropdown? so for example if the date is `02/11/16` then it will default select 
`01/28/16`
Basically what I'm asking for is an if statement that default selects the drop-down that the date is within

```
<?php
                    date_default_timezone_set('US/Eastern');
                    $currenttime = date('d:m:y:h:i:s A');
                    list($day,$month,$year) = split(':',$currenttime);
                    $currentdate = "$month/$day/$year";
?>


<form>
<select>
<option>01/14/16</option>
<option>01/28/16</option>
<option>02/14/16</option>
///the list goes on for ages so i saved time and cropped out the rest of the dates.
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: How would you decide it is in billing period?

Comment: Why don't you just do `$currentdate = date("m/d/y")` instead of splitting the time?

Comment: @Sougata Looks like the billing period is the range between the dates in the menu.

Comment: @Barmar Seems to be. I guess `> 01/28/16` & `< 02/14/16` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all the dates in an array, and loop through them. Then you can test them and decide whether the current date is in the billing period.

```
$dates = array('16-01-14',
               '16-01-28',
               '16-02-14',
                ...);
$currentdate = date('y-m-d');

?>
<form>
<select>
<?php
foreach ($date as $i => $d) {
    if ($currentdate >= $d && ($i == count($dates)-1 || $currentdate < $dates[$i+1])) {
        $selected = "selected";
    } else {
        $selected = "";
    }
    list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $d);
    echo "<option $selected>$month/$day/$year</option>";
}
?>
</select>
</form>
```

I changed the format of `$currentdate` to `y-m-d` so that they can be compared as strings to see if the date is in a range.

As it loops through the list of dates, it tests whether the current date is between that date and the next date in the array (or it's the last date in the array). If it is, it adds the `selected` attribute to the `<option>`.

Comment: @barmar Thankyou for the response is it possible to ask how this works? If not its fine I will still mark this question as answered just wondering if you could be more specific; what I dont understand is the foreach function?

Comment: I've added some more explanation to the answer.

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate the help